# For else with list, and folder transfer

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop

I have multiple files in a subfolder that need to copy to another main folder with specified subfolder name with datetime, means **A1/B/C/D/D.txt** copy to **A2/B/C/D/datetime_username/D.txt**, there is multiple folder in the dir B,C,D maybe B1,B2... the user decide which subfolder to be transfer

now im trying with the basic things its to print the path of D folder. The folder im trying is in my desktop.

```
    import os, shutil
    
    os.chdir('C:\\path')
    
    def main():
        lvl1 = ['Typ','GFP2']
        lvl2 = ['A0','A1']
        lvl3 = ['SCAN','MBIST']
    
        project = input("Enter project: ")
        
        #Validation
        for s in lvl1:
    
            if s == project:
                src1 = 'IDC\\{}'.format(s)
                
                stepping = input("Enter Stepping: ")
                
                for l2 in lvl2:
                    if l2 == stepping:
                        #shutil.copytree()
                        src2 = src1+'\\{}'.format(l2)
    
                        thirdlvl = input("Enter SCAN/MBIST: ")
    
                        for l3 in lvl3:
                            if l3 == thirdlvl:
                                src3 = src2+'\\{}'.format(l3)
                                print(src3)
                            
    
                else:
                    print("Stepping not found")
                    break
    
        else:
            print("Project name not found")
        
        
    main()
```

and i will get
'''

```
Enter project: Typ
Enter Stepping: A0
Enter SCAN/MBIST: SCAN
IDC\Typ\A0\SCAN
Stepping not found
```

'''

How if i want to print the "Stepping not found" only when there is no stepping found, now it prints even when there is this folder exist.

Thank you

Comment: The "else" won't be executed only if there is a "break" in the for-loop. Maybe you should instead add a flag variable to set true if stepping was found and check it after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add (or change position of) `break` in your `for-else`. A minimum modification is:

```
def main():
    lvl1 = ['Typ','GFP2']
    lvl2 = ['A0','A1']
    lvl3 = ['SCAN','MBIST']

    project = input("Enter project: ")
    
    #Validation
    for s in lvl1:

        if s == project:
            src1 = 'IDC\\{}'.format(s)
            
            stepping = input("Enter Stepping: ")
            
            for l2 in lvl2:
                if l2 == stepping:
                    #shutil.copytree()
                    src2 = src1+'\\{}'.format(l2)

                    thirdlvl = input("Enter SCAN/MBIST: ")

                    for l3 in lvl3:
                        if l3 == thirdlvl:
                            src3 = src2+'\\{}'.format(l3)
                            print(src3)
                    break
            else:
                print("Stepping not found")
                
            break
    else:
        print("Project name not found")
```

You can also get rid of `for-loop` by

```
def main():
    lvl1 = ['Typ','GFP2']
    lvl2 = ['A0','A1']
    lvl3 = ['SCAN','MBIST']

    project = input("Enter project: ")

    #Validation
    if project in lvl1:
        src1 = 'IDC\\{}'.format(project)
        
        stepping = input("Enter Stepping: ")
        
        if stepping in lvl2:
            #shutil.copytree()
            src2 = src1+'\\{}'.format(stepping)

            thirdlvl = input("Enter SCAN/MBIST: ")

            if thirdlvl in lvl3:
                src3 = src2+'\\{}'.format(thirdlvl)
                print(src3)
        else:
            print("Stepping not found")
    else:
        print("Project name not found")
```

The multi-layer `if-else` structure is not needed. Here is a modification. I also uses `os.path.join()` which is more suitable for handling paths than string operations:

```
import os, shutil

working_dir = os.path.join("C:/", "path")
os.chdir(working_dir)

def main():
    lvl1 = ['Typ','GFP2']
    lvl2 = ['A0','A1']
    # lvl3 = ['SCAN','MBIST']
    
    project = input("Enter project: ")
    if project not in lvl1:
        print("Project name not found")
        return
    
    stepping = input("Enter Stepping: ")
    if stepping not in lvl2:
        print("Stepping not found")
        return

    thirdlvl = input("Enter SCAN/MBIST: ")
    
    src = os.path.join(project, stepping, thirdlvl)
    print("src", src)
    
    if not os.path.exists(src):
        print("Src not exists")

main()
```

You can even automate the process more by letting `os.listdir()` list all the sub-folders for you.

```
import os, shutil

working_dir = os.path.join("C:/", "path")
os.chdir(working_dir)

def main():    
    project = input("Enter project: ")
    lvl1 = os.listdir(working_dir) # list all the directories under the working directory.
    if project not in lvl1:
        print("Project name not found")
        return # if you want to exit when not finding the project folder.
    
    stepping = input("Enter Stepping: ") # list all the directories under the project directory.
    lvl2 = os.listdir(os.path.join(working_dir, project))
    if stepping not in lvl2:
        print("Stepping not found")
        return # if you want to exit when not finding the stepping folder.
        
    thirdlvl = input("Enter SCAN/MBIST: ")
    
    src = os.path.join(project, stepping, thirdlvl)
    print("src", src)
    
    if not os.path.exists(src):
        print("Src not exists")

main()
```